# Filling an array with random numbers using a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, crash

Hello Im trying to fill my array with random numbers from 1 to 50 using a pointer. When I try to do this the program crashes.
This is the declaration.

```
populate(arraySize, numArray);
```

and the code

```
void populate(int size, int *ptr)
{
int counter = 0;
srand(unsigned(time(0)));
while (counter < size++)
{
    ptr[counter] = (rand() % 50) + 1;
    counter++;
}

}
```

There are no errors with the code and it runs it just crashes when this method is called

Answer (score 1):

```
srand(unsigned(time(0)));
void populate(int size, int *ptr)
{
int counter = 0;

while (counter < size)
{
    ptr[counter] = (rand() % 50) + 1;
    counter++;
}

}
```

Remove the size++ and change it to size.

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to call `srand` in `populate` if you call `populate` more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be

```
int randomNumber () { return (std::rand()%50 +1); }

void populate(int size, int * ptr)
{
        std::srand ( unsigned ( std::time(0) ) );
        std::generate (ptr,ptr+size-1, randomNumber);
}
```

It is assumed that prior to call this function, user much do some range validation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to iterate through the array. You wrote `counter < size++`, which means incrementing `size` (I guess it's the variable that's supposed to hold the number of items) after checking for `counter < size`. The `++` operator does not give you another value that equals `size + 1`; instead, it increments `size` the same way `size = size + 1` does. So `size` will increase the same time `counter` increases, and the index will eventually go out of bounds, and the program will crash when trying to write to that location.

Plus, as of `srand`, you only need to call it once (e.g. in your `main()`).